# Display one to many mapping in pandas dataframe after groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name" : ["a", "a", "b", "b", "b"], "Numbers" : [1, 3, 2, 4, 6]})
```

I want to display, it such that for each name appearing once(not repeated), its numbers a listed with each in a new line.
I can do this :

```
df.groupby(["Name"]).agg({"Numbers" : lambda x : list(x)}).reset_index()
```

Which displays like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDFpX.png). I want to "unroll" the list so as to make it something like this

```
"a"    1
       3
"b"    2
       4
       6
```

How do I go about this. I have tried getting the `"\n".join(list(x))`, but instead of displaying on new lines, it shows with `\n` chars.

Answer (score 0):

```
def unroll(g):
    is_first = True
    num = g[1].values.tolist()
    print(g[0], num[0][0])
    for n in num:
        print(" ", n[0])

for x in df.groupby('Name'):
    unroll(x)
```